# Can I also call my brother my relative?

Tags: word-meaning

Relative is a member of your family.  But some people say that it refers to your cousins, uncles, grandparents, and aunts.  Does that mean I cannot call my brother and sister relatives?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, yes. You are connected through your family's bloodline and are thus relatives.

> **[relative](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/relative?s=t)**
>
> a person who is **connected with another or others by blood** or marriage

*Source: Dictionary.com*

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to my sibling using the proper more specific term, but they would certainly be lumped in with relatives if I were talking about a group of people with different levels of family closeness.